# Origin of "the wrong end of the stick"

Tags: etymology, slang

If someone has [the **wrong** end of the stick](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/get-the-wrong-end-of-the-stick) it means they've misunderstood something.

If they've got [the **shitty** end of the stick](http://dictionary.reference.com/idioms/shitty+end+of+the+stick) it means they've got a bad deal in some bargain or share-out. This doesn't seem particularly close to the **wrong** end meaning - so unless someone convinces me different, I'm not inclined to think these idioms share a common origin.

Does anyone know where either or both of these expressions come from?

Comment: http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/455954?uid=3739936&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=47699002555697

Comment: Wait, if you grabbed a stick by the shitty end, you wouldn't think you'd grabbed the wrong end? I would.

Comment: @bee.catt: I guess. But to be honest, even if the shit was on the *other* end of the stick, I'd rather not have to get that particular stick (I'd rather get ***either*** end of a completely non-shitty stick! :)

Comment: True enough. But if you must touch a stick with shit on it (and hey, shit happens, so it's not an impossibility), I would say the non-shitty end would be the right end and vice versa.

Comment: @bee.catt: <slaps forehead> I momentarily forgot! Yeah - shit happens (tell that to all the people with constipation! :)

Comment: @bee.catt: After another post or two the system will suggest we should take this discussion into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/), but we prolly won't get shot. Well, *you* won't - but I might, because they know where I live (I won a T-shirt last year, so I had to tell them where to mail it! :)

Comment: @bee.catt: I don't "chat" here very often, but every now and then I poke my head in for a bit. Maybe see you there. But really we shouldn't clutter up the main site like this. If a mod deletes the last few comments I shan't mind, and if I get upbraided for my part in it I won't feel hard-done-by. I still don't expect to get shot, but who knows what sanctions TPTB might impose?

Comment: I see it more often as "the short end of the stick," which wouldn't fit with the outhouse explanations. In fact, I can't figure out how a stick can have a long end or short end.

Comment: @gmcgath: I've just discovered from [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=short+end+of+the+stick%2Cwrong+end+of+the+stick&year_start=1830&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) that ***short** end of the stick* is overwhelmingly favoured in the US, but that form is virtually unknown in the UK. Also that the US *short* only rose to prominence around WW2, whereas the UK *wrong* seems to have been well-used much earlier...

Comment: ...Apparently *The American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms* says the expression *originated in the 1400s as "**worse end of the staff**" and changed to the current wording only in the late 1800s.*

Comment: The one about the spatula in the dark out house is the one that I knew about, and fortunately not from actual experience. Thankfully, on the three or four times that I have been forced to use out door plumbing there were newspapers or a Sears catalog and it was not dark.

Comment: @gmcgath A stick can have a long end and a short end if you split it in half and then give one person one end and another person the other end.

Comment: I don't know if you were aware but an (almost) anonymous user posted, what I thought, was a very plausible and sensible answer on EL&U yesterday. Only thing is, he posted it as a question which was, objectively speaking, a duplicate of yours. [What is the origin of “Get a hold of the short/wrong end of the stick”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/283103/what-is-the-origin-of-get-a-hold-of-the-short-wrong-end-of-the-stick?lq=1) maybe a mod could transform it into an answer and post it here? What do you think?

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I find that "answer posted as question" totally unconvincing as an explanation for the origin of either/both current senses, so I wouldn't upvote it anyway. It's always open to the OP to copy his text here, as has been suggested/implied by comments. Or *you* could copy it yourself - make it community wiki so you can't be accused of plagiarism, and include a link back to the misplaced "original". I don't really see why mods should have to do *all* the drudge work.

Comment: A typical dismissive comment by you, a habit of yours whenever I politely and genuinely propose anything that involves a minimum of "legwork" by the mods. I am in no rush to do as you suggested, (copy and paste the answer, and turn it into a community wiki) as I am almost 100% convinced you would swiftly downvote it. I will; however, post an answer containing a link to that page so it may be of service to future visitors.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I don't understand why you're so tetchy. I don't recall *ever* making hostile personal comments to you, but you've been doing it to me more and more lately. You asked what I thought of that "misplaced" answer and I told you. Including the fact that *I wouldn't upvote it*. Why do you interpret that as *I would **downvote** it*, then attack me for not voting the way *you* want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [The Phrase Finder](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/end-of-the-stick.html), the two share the same origin, not really diverging in meaning until 1850 or so.

Comment: The link doesn't work for me. This one does: http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/16/messages/241.html

Comment: This is really an inadequate answer, inasmuch as  the OP should have insisted that you provided a summary of the meaning behind the two expressions,  link rot is an occupational hazard around these parts, and the best answers on EL&U should be self-contained.

Answer (score 7):

Before toilet paper and Sears catalogs, there was a wooden spatula called *the stick*. If you were in the outhouse after dark and you had to find the stick in the dark, you had a good  chance of finding the wrong, dirty, shitty end of the stick. Not everyone could afford candles or lanterns, and sometimes the wind would blow them out anyway.

Comment: Is there a source for this?

Comment: @Norman Sherrod Folks back then must have had one h*ll of an immune system.

Comment: If there now was such a stick, what was it's purpose?

Comment: Sorry, are you saying people wiped their rears with a spatula? Hmm.

Answer (score 5):

When harnessing a matched team, one uses a stick called an "evener" attached by a pin at its center to the wagon or farm implement.  Each end of the evener is attached to the harness of each draft animal. When pulling with 2 animals of different size (am unmatched team) one moves the location of the center hole (fulcrum) towards the side near the larger animal.  Each animal is then pulling an amount of weight corresponding to its size, thus the term "evener".  The larger animal is pulling more of the load because he has the "short end of the stick".

Comment: Fascinating. Do you have any supporting references for this? Not that I'm *trying* to rule it out, but my gut feel is that "load-bearing" ***sticks*** are rarely identified by that word (they're usually ***rods*** or ***poles***). But perhaps usage was different a long time ago.

Comment: I have no linguistic or academic sources, but any good teamster or farrier would use this expression & know what it means.

Comment: I'll try to find a source.

Comment: The evener I reference is a "double tree".  An evener behind a single horse is a **single tree** An evener is also called a **whiffletree**,**whippletree** or sometimes **swiveltree**.  For simplicity's sake, teamsters call all eveners **sticks**.  **Poles** are attached to wagons & go between two horses hitched as a team.

Comment: I have 3 responses to my inquiries. Although the sources not etymological or grammatical, they are real & current vernacular uses of the term.

Comment: Neil Dimmock - “ya i think its where the term comes from”

Comment: Paul Bishop -  “Down here we call a wiffle tree a close up single tree that hangs right up on the horses britchen they used them with a single horse on a hay rope. I totally agree with the short end of the stick.”

Comment: Peter Wright – “Shure.  When I hitch up Karens little mare with Ruben he gets the short end.”

Comment: I can't find any of your cited texts. Do you mean you've asked each of those three people, and those are the replies you got? Usually on ELU we expect [links](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6zDCLcia6w) to online sources, so we can assess cited usages or opinions *with full context*.

Answer (score 2):

The wrong end of the stick is usually explained as having come from Roman culture. Toilet paper had not been invented in Roman times so, they usually used a sponge on a stick, like this http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-AKCoVbCisFw/UCnEu4eqv1I/AAAAAAAAAew/OzR_GuiOqDM/s1600/spongestick.jpg The end with the sponge, was used to clean themselves. If someone was not paying attention when it came time to use a stick, they could pick it up by the wrong end. There is an explanation here http://www.cracked.com/article_16108_the-bizarre-history-10-common-sayings_p2.html

That link also says:

*There is, though, another origin that's widely held to be the true one. The origin pertains to walking sticks and accidentally grabbing the dirty, non-handled end, the "wrong end."*

Answer (score 2):

Nay, the stick with the shitty end was not used to clean oneself; it was used to knock over the pile of shit lest it become too high and reach the hole. Also, you would want the pile to be relatively flat so that you could dust it with ashes, and thus limit the smell. (Have you people never used an outhouse?)

Answer (score 1):

The "stick" refers to a printer's stick when typeset were physical letters.   A novice would often fill the printer stick in the wrong order, in which case, the print would not be as expected, e.g. "print" would appear as 'tnirp', hence, grabbing the wrong end of the stick.

Answer (score 1):

The origin of the two idioms is thought be related to [***argumentum baculum***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_baculum) or *the argument of the cudgel* (or staff, hence stick). 
 The best explanation can be found [here](http://www.knowyourphrase.com/phrase-meanings/Short-End-of-the-Stick.html).

The picture is literally that of a master beating a servant. If you **get the wrong end of the stick**, you are the recipient of the blows from the lucky master who holds the *right end.*

To say that you [*get the wrong end of the stick*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wrong+end+of+the+stick,+the) simply implies misunderstanding or wrong facts.

To say that you [*have the short (or dirty) end of the stick*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/short%20end%20of%20the%20stick) is to have the least desirable part of a bargain or the worst end of a bargain.

Answer (score 1):

According to "The Toilet - an unspoken history" - BBC documentary. Romans sat on communal outhouses - underneath them was running water (non-potable) that carried the waste away. In front of them was running water for washing. They would use sticks with sponges on them to clean their bum.  Of course, if it was dark, they were in danger of grabbing the wrong end of the stick.
I had lots of questions after this - why weren't the sticks cleaned after each use? Why didn't people have their own personal sticks? What's the point of having two sets of channels for running water and cleanliness - only to have to use a dirty stick?

Comment: Hi @Jan Perkins, Welcome to ELU. Good answer but I see that you have stated many questions at the end. I need you to recognize that this is not a discussion forum but a Q&A site. You could use the comment section if you still want to ask them or make a separate question for it if it isn't entertained there. Also, it is mandatory to include a link/support/evidence to the BBC documentary or rather any other claim you make here. Please have a look at http://english.stackexchange.com/help to know how things work here!

Comment: I have seen this explanation before.  In fact, I think it was here, maybe a year ago.

Comment: Bring your own sponge.

Answer (score 1):

It "wrong end of the stick" comes from when a printer loads moveable type on the type form ("the stick") from the left facing up instead the right facing up. If you load from left you have the wrong end of tbe stick.

The short stick comes from when persons draw straws or sticks from a bunch to select sombody for duty or a reward.

Comment: This could do with some supporting evidence for the definitions you've given.

Answer (score 0):

Sesame is correct.
The *shitty end of stick* is to knock the top off the turd cone in an outhouse. 
The outhouse has no lights so if I put the stick upside down, the next person might grab the shitty end of the stick.

Comment: turd cone? That's a new one for me.

Comment: You may want to dig a new hole or call Don's Johns to have your pile sucked out if the cone is high enough you need to knock the top of with a stick.  

We eat crayons so our poop comes out rainbow colored and keep a "No Shit Stick" Stick coated in teflon next to the toilet.  

The "No Shit Stick" Stick is  for breaking up large solid anaconda sized feces when the family poop scissors are unable to cut through the digested food.  

Opioid Induced Constipation (OIC) runs in our inbred family of morons that get hurt in construction accidents.  A stick and scissors is cheaper than Movantic.

Answer (score 0):

'Grasp the wrong end of the stick'.  I suspect that literalist explanations about sticks may be later, as the expression modulated in English from an earlier 'grasp the wrong end of the twig'.  Double word-play here, twig from the Scottish Gaelic tuig = to understand.

Comment: Interesting, but I think your etymology is unlikely. OED records *twig = watch, look at, inspect* from 1764, with "origin unascertained". But the cognate *understand, comprehend* sense isn't recorded until 1815.

Answer (score 0):

Just watched a youtube video on the subject called the great stink! https://youtu.be/MJWLJxiWgDY  It goes back to Romans and Hadrians Wall.  There was a laddle used to wash your backside off.  Sometimes, you could grab the "wrong end of the stick"

Comment: Aha, so a ladle, not a stick? Not: laddle.....:)

Answer (score 0):

In the 1980's I led an ODA funded project to improve wast management and sanitation in Kumasi, Ghana' second city.  One aspect of the project was to improve latrine design on which we cooperated with the London School of Hygiene and Tropical Medicine.   Most villages around Kumasi could not afford water-borne sanitation and so used latrines which were run very efficiently as a village service.  A field was reserved for the purpose an a block of latrines was in use until filled and then the buildings move progressively around the perimeter of the field and by the time a complete circuit had been made the original deposits had been composted.  The huts were of quite sophisticated design, tepee like, with a funnel to a hole in the roof to create and air-draft to expell smell and insects.  There was, of course, no toilet paper and neither the luxury of runnning water.  Some places used large leaves but mostly each villager had their own stick which was left propped up outside rather like cues in a snooker hall.  It was obviously important go hold the right end.  There may of course be other derivations from other places but that was certainly the usage from Ghana.   Geoff Mills

Answer (score 0):

This is the best answer I came up with.

> This phrase refers to a walking stick held upside down, which does not help a walker much. Originating in the 1400s as worse end of the staff, this term was changed to the current wording only in the late 1800s.
>
> Alternative: The Romans invented the flush toilet, but not toilet paper; and their lavatories were communal affairs, where one would go and chew the fat over the day's happenings with whoever else was in at the time. Personal cleanliness was addressed with a cloth or a sponge which lived in a bowl of water at one end of the lavatorium, and which was passed from person to person by means of a stick. It is easy - if rather stomach-churning - to imagine someone deep in conversation not looking when the stick was passed to them, and therefore getting hold of the wrong end of it. Thanks to Robert Day.
> <sub>[English for Students](http://www.english-for-students.com/Wrong-End.html)</sub>

Answer (score -1):

A means to clean ones own behind. When Romans had slaves the stick was passed from slave to Roman and back again after use, hence someone (usually the slave) occasionally got the shitty end of the stick. Common in shared communal outhouses. I have seen period art depicting this also. If anyone has watched the tv series Spartacus then you would have seen some footage depicting this also. I would say that there would be many common references that this saying would have came from.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Daniel. Do you have any other credible sources that support this thesis?

Comment: Unless Roman slaves were complaining in English about toilet duty or you can show some Latin equivalent that Caesar brought with him, this is merely folk etymology.  Doesn't mean it's wrong; just means there's no way to verify it.  And, no, watching a TV series doesn't count.  I'd recommend you withdraw your answer.