# Is the usage of idiom, “get hold of the wrong end of the stick” situation specific?

Tags: etymology, idioms, word-usage

I came across the idiom, “get hold of the wrong end of the stick” in the following sentence of the scene where Barry Calvert, an FBI agent tells his colleague, Mark Andrews about the statement of an illegal Greek immigrant on suspected assassination scheme in Jeffery Archer’s fiction, “Shall we tell the President” P.37:

> “I don’t believe a word of it,” Barry said immediately. “With his
>   English, he could easily have **got hold of the wrong end of the stick**. It was
>   probably quite innocent. People curse the President all the time. My
>   father does, but that doesn’t mean he would kill her.”

I checked the meaning of “get hold of the wrong end of the stick” with a couple of dictionaries:

Cambridge Dictionary defines it as “to not understand a *situation* correctly.”
The FreeDictionary defines it exactly in the same way as Cambridge - “(informal). to not understand a *situation* correctly”

Kenkyusha Publishing’s Readers English Japanese Dictionary defines it as “make an error of the judgment (of *situation*).

While the definitions of the above three English and English Japanese dictionaries are all “*Situation specific*,” Collins English Dictionary defines it as “a complete misunderstanding of *a situation, explanation, etc*.”

Can I use “get hold of the wrong end of the stick other than a “situation,” e.g. for meaning of word(s), message, statement, somebody’s notion, view, intent, and idea?  Can I say “I get hold of the wrong end of the stick on his remarks (or instructions)”?

Secondarily, what is the origin of this idiom?

**Correction:**

I was reminded of that I dropped “end of the” from “get hold of the wrong end of the stick by TimLymington's advice.

It’s careless but a great mistake that occurred when I was transcribing the original text of Archer’s fiction. My apology.

I suspected if I should cancel this question. However, the definitions of all dictionaries of the idiom, and my question about whether the idiom is “situation specific,” or not remain the same.
So I ventured to leave it as it is by making necessary corrections.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't "get hold of the wrong end of the stick"?

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67813

Comment: TimLimington.Thanks a lot for your pointing out my mistake. I dropped “end of. “ It was “hold of the wrong end of the stick.” I was careless and my apology for confusing you and many of users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that not a single reference work considers *wrong stick* as a variant of the well-known idiom, this corruption is likely to be a mistake (albeit quite possibly a deliberate one).

The origin of the two related idioms (see below) is thought be related to [***argumentum baculum***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_baculum) or *the argument of the cudgel* (or staff, hence stick). 
 The best explanation can be found [here](http://www.knowyourphrase.com/phrase-meanings/Short-End-of-the-Stick.html).

The picture is literally that of a master beating a servant. If you **get the wrong end of the stick**, you are the recipient of the blows from the lucky master who holds the *right end.*

To say that you [*get the wrong end of the stick*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wrong+end+of+the+stick,+the) simply implies misunderstanding or wrong facts (and is not *situation-specific*, assuming I get the drift of your question).

To say that you [*have the short (or dirty) end of the stick*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/short%20end%20of%20the%20stick) is to have the least desirable part of a bargain or the worst end of a bargain.

*Get hold of the wrong stick* does not appear to make much sense. It implies there are a few sticks to choose from and (more implausibly) that one of them is right for the purpose. In the context provided, the author alludes to the subject's deficiency in the knowledge of English Language which could well lead to a misunderstanding on his part (a curse being misinterpreted as an actual plot to kill). It may even be the case that the distortion of this well-known idiom is deliberate and intended to disparage the Greek man's poor grasp of English.

Answer (score 4):

The *wrong **end** of the stick* is at [Question 67813](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67813/) and linked to [CUP Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/get-the-wrong-end-of-the-stick).

To ***get hold of the wrong stick*** is to misunderstand something **completely:** not even holding the right stick, let alone the right end of the stick.

> The good news might be that even though you got hold of the wrong end of the stick, you didn't get hold of the wrong stick entirely.
>
> [The Student Room (UK)](http://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/showthread.php?t=2009317)
>
> ---
>
> ...  once in a while, the foodie network in Atlanta really does get hold of the wrong stick.
>
> [Marie, Let's Eat (Woodstock GA)](http://marieletseat.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/canyons-burger-company-woodstock-ga.html)

Answer (score 0):

In the sense of your Question no, “get hold of the wrong end of the stick” is not *situation specific*

*situation specific* means dealing with "a given situation" not, as your details suggest dealing "only with situations".

Can I use “get hold of the wrong end of the stick other than a “situation,” e.g. for meaning of word(s), message, statement, somebody’s notion, view, intent, and idea? Yes, you can.

Can I say “I get hold of the wrong end of the stick on his remarks (or instructions)”? Yes, you can.

Still, those examples beg the real Question…

Answer (score -1):

The explanations of 'grabbing the wrong end of the stick' seem to be all over the place.  I read the TRUE explanation in a unimpeachable source about 55 years ago (1965).  That source was Playboy magazine, published by the one and only Hugh Hefner.  The magazine reported that during the Middle Ages, if one had to defecate, there was a room in the castle where one would relieve him or herself.  This being an era of no toilet paper, a stick was used to do the wiping.  At night, this could be a problem, as one couldn't tell which end of the stick to hold, and the one to wipe ones ass.  People would occasionally 'grab the wrong end of the stick', so to speak, and be royally pissed off.

Comment: Playboy is not considered an authority on the English language.

Comment: True or not, it's consistent with history and amusing, however we usually require links to sources here. Please take the [tour] and when you have a moment, read-up in the [help] about how we work. Welcome to English Language and Usage Sedona.

Answer (score -3):

I think it comes from Roman times. People who went to the toilet wriped their butt with a stick with something atratched to it, like a sponge or cloth. Obviously, if you were to get hold of the wrong end of the stick, your hands would get shitty

Comment: Ness, did you read the other answers? Everything in your answer has already been proposed in other answers. Do you have any evidence to support your answer? Note that an answer on this site is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]**. It might also be worthwhile reading some of the more popular questions on our site to get a feel for the kind of answers we prefer. :-)