# What is the origin of “Get a hold of the short/wrong end of the stick”?

Tags: etymology, idiom-meaning

I know this is a duplicate, of this question: [Origin of "the wrong end of the stick"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67813/origin-of-the-wrong-end-of-the-stick?lq=1)
but none of the answers are can be considered fact.

**I propose this answer:**

> The [*split tally*](http://cs-exhibitions.uni-klu.ac.at/index.php?id=319) was a technique which became common in medieval Europe, which was constantly short of money (coins) and predominantly illiterate, in order to record bilateral exchange and debts.
>
> A stick (squared hazelwood sticks were most common) was marked with a system of notches and then split lengthwise. This way the two halves both record the same notches and each party to the transaction received one half of the marked stick as proof. Later this technique was refined in various ways and became virtually tamper proof. One of the refinements was to make the two halves of the stick of different lengths. **The longer part was called *stock*** and was given to the party which had advanced money (or other items) to the receiver.
>
> The **shorter portion of the stick was called** ***foil*** and was given to the party which had received the funds or goods. Using this technique each of the parties had an identifiable record of the transaction. The natural irregularities in the surfaces of the tallies where they were split would mean that only the original two halves would fit back together perfectly, and so would verify that they were matching halves of the same transaction.
>
> If one party tried to unilaterally change the value of his half of the tally stick by adding more notches, those notches would not be on the other tally stick and would be revealed as an attempted forgery.
>
> The *split tally* was accepted as legal proof in medieval courts and the Napoleonic Code (1804) still makes reference to the tally stick in Article 1333. Along the Danube and in Switzerland the tally was still used in the 20th century in rural economies.
>
> The person with the short end of the stick was in a bad spot because they were in debt to the person holding the longer side.

Source: Virtual Exhibitions in Informatics [Tally Sticks](http://cs-exhibitions.uni-klu.ac.at/index.php?id=319)

An image of a medieval tally stick, courtesy of Wikipedia

[image]

> Medieval English [*split tally stick*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tally_stick) (front and reverse view). The stick is notched and inscribed to record a debt owed to the rural dean of Preston Candover, Hampshire, of a tithe of 20d each on 32 sheep, amounting to a total sum of £2 13s. 4d.

Comment: This is overbearing and difficult to keep up with. I would suggest editing and getting to the point in like -2 paragraphs...then maybe you could keep someones attention

Comment: Hi James. Thanks for deciding to contribute. Welcome. However this isn't the appropriate way to go about proposing a question and answer. It's much better to write your question here, and then if you believe you know the answer, write a separate post answering the question (click on the 'answer' button).. Please have a look at [The Tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) which will tell you more about how things work here.

Comment: Why in heaven's name would you post an answer as a new question? I really don't understand this. Your answer will be seen by anyone who sees questions by recent activity. At least there, you can get upvotes. Here, it's dead in the water.

Comment: Maybe a mod could copy and paste this answer on the original question?

Comment: Damn! I just looked at the original question, and this answer is by far the best of the bunch. +1 from me! Why didn't you post this answer there, mate? It would have been ethically more correct if you had cited the source too, but I'll forgive you.

Comment: This looks very convincing (as an answer, not a question), but there's one thing I'm struggling with: how does splitting a stick "lengthwise" leave two portions of different lengths? Or did the transverse *snapping* of the stick supercede the *splitting*, with the "irregularities" as described serving the purpose of the original "notches"?

Comment: @JHCL https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tally_stick (see image)