# Is there a word for one end of a dichotomy?

Tags: single-word-requests

A common definition of a dichotomy is:

> division into two [parts](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dichotomy)

or

> mutually exclusive or contradictory [groups or entities](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dichotomy)...

or

> A division or contrast between two [things](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dichotomy)...

Parts, groups, entities and things are all fine words, but they're all very broad. Almost anything can be a thing, or an entity. Practically everything is a part of something or a group of other things. None of those terms is in any way specific to a dichotomy.

Is there a term that specifically means one end of a dichotomy, or even something close to that?

If not, what's the closest we can get?

Perhaps something defined in terms of opposition to the other, like [antithesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antithesis)?

The sentence that has sent me in search of this (probably non-existent word) is:

> There is a tradeoff between password length, and how often we expect users to change passwords, and we have chosen the wrong *end-of-the-dichotomy*.

I'd like to find a single word to complete the sentence, if there is one.

Comment: There is no dichotomy in the context you describe. How long a password is (required to be) and how often it must be changed are not notions that form a dichotomy—there's no contradiction or mutual exclusiveness to them. What you're really looking for is a word for the two poles of a situation that entails a tradeoff.

Comment: Moiety is what is used in anthropology for one side of a group split into two.

Answer (score 6):

The two opposites distinguished by a dichotomy or antithesis are the ***[poles](http://thefreedictionary.com/pole)*** of that dichotomy or antithesis:

> Either of two antithetical ideas, propensities, forces, or positions. (American Heritage)
>
> Either of two mutually exclusive or opposite actions, opinions, etc. (Collins)

For your specific sample sentence, however, the following metaphor might be preferable:

> There is a tradeoff between password length, and how often we expect users to change passwords, and we have *got the wrong end of the stick* on that [or perhaps *we have got hold of the wrong end of that stick*].

On that metaphoric expression, see [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67813/origin-of-the-wrong-end-of-the-stick) on this site, or [this TFD entry](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+the+wrong+end+of+the+stick). Both point to its primary meaning as a kind of mis-perception or misunderstanding—that is, an error more theoretical than practical—but that seems to fit the case well enough.

Comment: Perfect idiom, but I want to avoid idioms. I can't count on only having native English readers.

Answer (score 1):

> There is a tradeoff between password length, and how often we expect
>   users to change passwords, and we have chosen the wrong **side**.

Or if you don't like "side", see synonyms for "side" as related to ["angle"](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/side).